# How to traslate text(months, days of week, etc) of syncfusion react scheduler component

Tags: reactjs, components, scheduler, syncfusion

Please i need helo to traslate names of months, days of week to spanish of How to traslate text(month, days of week, etc) of  syncfusion react scheduler component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate the schedule to Spanish culture with the help of the **locale** property and **load** method of the **L10n** class and for the same, you can refer to the following sample.

**Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/ej2-react-schedule-with-es-locale-sample?file=index.js

Kindly refer to the below UG link for localizing the Syncfusion schedule component.

**UG(EJ2 React Schedule Globalization):** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/localization/#globalization

Regards,
Ravikumar Venkatesan

Comment: Thank you Ravikumar, it worked for me. By chance, you know how to change the secondary color (pink when its selected), for another color